# How do I format a y-axis 'y' in matplotlib going between pandas dataframes and simple variables?

Tags: python, matplotlib

CSV1only is a dataframe uploaded from a CSV

Let CSV1only as a dataframe be a column such that:

TRADINGITEMID:

1233

2455

3123

1235

5098

as a small example

How can I plot a scatterplot accordingly, specifically the y-axis?

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

CSV1only.plot(kind='scatter',x='TRADINGITEMID', y= [1,2], color='b')
plt.xlabel('TRADINGITEMID Numbers')
plt.ylabel('Range')
plt.title('Distribution of ItemIDNumbers')
```

and it doesn't work because of the y.

So, my main question is just how I can get a 0, 1, 2 y-axis for this scatter plot, as I want to make a distribution graph.

The following code doesn't work because it doesn't match the amount of rows included in the original TRADINGITEMID column, which has 5000 rows:

```
newcolumn_values = [1, 2]
CSV1only['un et deux'] = newcolumn_values
#and then I changed the y = [1,2] from before into y = ['un et deux']
```

Therefore the solution would need to work from any integer 1 to N, N being the # of rows. Yet, it would only have a range of [0, 2] or some [0, m], m being some arbitrary integer.

Don't need to worry about the actual pandas data frame CSV1only. 
The 'TRADINGITEMIDNUMBERS' contains 5000 rows of unique numbers, so  I just wanna plot those numbers on a line, with the y-axis being instances (which will never pass 1 since it is unique).

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Gotcha -- I'll edit my prompt accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the following: You need to generate y-values starting from 0 until `n-1` where `n` is the total number of rows

```
y = np.arange(len(CSV1only['TRADINGITEMID']))

plt.scatter(CSV1only['TRADINGITEMID'], y, c='DarkBlue')
```